# Email alert for task due date

Tags: workflow, email, alert, tasks

I am getting email alert on the creation of a new task, but not for due date.

Can someone help? For testing purpose, I kept it as 30mins. Previously I tried for 1 day but no luck either.

[image: SPD WF steps/stages]

Comment: Add some logging to see where the workflow is stuck. Does the worklow give an error? Why do you have the "Loop:6"?

Comment: No Error message and Loop 6 is just a name nothing more - I need to have repetitive loop so that it keep checking the overdue and send mail unless the task status is complete

Comment: Yes, but is the loop6 needed? Seems not needed to me. Plus add logging so you can see where the workflow is at when running

Comment: Then how we check the due date repetedly for the task which have the status as Not completed. User need to keep getting reminder right

Comment: You transition to stage Overdue when status is not equal to completed, so there is your loop, no?

Answer (score 0):

This also works or me:
[image]

So I do not use the transition section to put the if-logic.